# Change material setting of texture

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, materials, node-editor

I have a quick question regarding a scene I'm working on. I have no idea if it's impossible or the easiest thing in the world, but if you want to take a look at the image I attached, I attached a transparent image onto a mesh with an existing node setting to make it appear plastic. I was wondering if there is anything I could do to make the text appear glittering like gold. Any advice?

Here is the blend file to those who asked. [image]

Much appreciated.[image: Pigma Sensei]

Comment: Can you add an image of your current node tree=

Comment: Could you possibly [upload your blend file](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/) so we can view your node setups and test solutions?

Comment: I added the blend file in my first post. Altered some things so that only the pencil is in the scene. Any help is much appreciated!